# I never had to save on sublime text before, today if wanted to get an output, I will have to save

Tags: sublimetext3

I am new to everything and I need help.
I used Sublime Text for a while and it always worked well. After saving the file for the first time, I never had to save til I closed Sublime Text. If I changed anything in my code, I could just press command+b and the changes would appear on the terminal window.

it doesn't work that way anymore. Whenever I want changes in the code to actually appear in the terminal window, I will have to save first.

What is the underlying issue here?

:

Answer (score 2):

You probably had **`Tools → Save All on Build`** checked previously. Check it again, and your file(s) will be saved when you run the Build command with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.